# ParserError: Error tokenizing data. (tradingWithPython library) - works on one computer, not other

Tags: python, pandas

I have two computers both running Python 3 with Jupyter Notebook. I have installed the tradingWithPython library on both.  I am trying to run the following command on each computer:

```
data = twp.yahooFinance.getHistoricData('SPY')
```

On one computer it works perfectly (which tells me the yahooFinance library is fine).  On the other computer I get the error below.  Can someone help me troubleshoot this?  Am I missing a library or something?

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ParserError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-18d2ebb8dde1> in <module>()
----> 1 data = twp.yahooFinance.getHistoricData('SPY')

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tradingWithPython/lib/yahooFinance.py in getHistoricData(symbols, **options)
    121 
    122     if isinstance(symbols,str):
--> 123         return getSymbolData(symbols,**options)
    124     else:
    125         data = {}

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tradingWithPython/lib/yahooFinance.py in getSymbolData(symbol, sDate, adjust, verbose)
    163 
    164     buf = io.StringIO(data.text) # create a buffer
--> 165     df = pd.read_csv(buf,index_col=0,parse_dates=True) # convert to pandas DataFrame
    166 
    167     # rename columns

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in parser_f(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, tupleize_cols, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, skipfooter, skip_footer, doublequote, delim_whitespace, as_recarray, compact_ints, use_unsigned, low_memory, buffer_lines, memory_map, float_precision)
    707                     skip_blank_lines=skip_blank_lines)
    708 
--> 709         return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    710 
    711     parser_f.__name__ = name

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    453 
    454     try:
--> 455         data = parser.read(nrows)
    456     finally:
    457         parser.close()

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in read(self, nrows)
   1067                 raise ValueError('skipfooter not supported for iteration')
   1068 
-> 1069         ret = self._engine.read(nrows)
   1070 
   1071         if self.options.get('as_recarray'):

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in read(self, nrows)
   1837     def read(self, nrows=None):
   1838         try:
-> 1839             data = self._reader.read(nrows)
   1840         except StopIteration:
   1841             if self._first_chunk:

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_low_memory()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error()

ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 4, saw 2
```

Answer (score 0):

After trying everything (reinstalling Python 3, uninstalling/reinstalling Pandas, tradingWithPython, and a few other libraries), nothing would work.  However, I could get it working on other computers.  I decided to nuke my new computer (wiped hard drive an reinstalled OS) and start over.  That solved the issue and the library is working good now without any issues.  I'm not sure what was causing the conflict, but I'm happy it's working now.

Fingers crossed the issue doesn't come back as I install other software.